# How to create GPUImage Lookup.png Resource

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage

I use GPUImage Framework to create Filter like this

```
GPUImagePicture *sourceImagePic = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:sourceImage];
GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lookup.png"]];

GPUImageLookupFilter *lookupImageFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
[sourceImagePic addTarget:lookupImageFilter];
[lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupImageFilter];

[lookupImageFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
[sourceImagePic processImage];
[lookupImageSource processImage];

resultImage = [lookupImageFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

return resultImage;
```

i want to know how to create lookupImageSource Resource ? like this 
[image]

i know i can use photoshop to finish this work, i just want to know can i use another way to export some kind of this picture ?

Answer (score 1):

This is 512x512 image containing information about color lookup.

You have to get original png. It is called neutral-lut.

In photoshop, you should apply your color-change layers to this original neutral-lut image.

I have this one.

But I don't know about image quality reduction during uploading to stackoverflow.

So If you have time, you may find neutral-lut in google.

After apply your color-change layer to this image, you can use this png to GPUImage Lookup Filter.

Happy coding!

[image: neutral-lut]